# Mozilla doesn't recognise the number attribute in HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, mozilla

I made some HTML code and wanted to take it for a testdrive on firefox. 
And apparently firefox doesnt recognise the numberattribute with the 'Number of bags'. 
I only get a textbox in mozilla. I doublechecked my code with Chrome and there I get what was to be expected.The small box with arrows to the side to change the amount inside the box.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://starbuzzcoffee.com/processorder.php" method="POST">
            <p>
                Number of bags: <input type="number" name="bags" min="1" max="10" ><br>
                Must arrive by date: <input type="date" name="date">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT: Apparently the feature is not supported by Mozilla.

Comment: Doesn't work in IE(9) either :/

Answer (score 2):

Number input type is not available in **Firefox** [2-24] and **IE** [5.5-9]:

*Note: iOS Safari, Android 4 and Chrome for Android show number input, but do not use "step", "min" or "max" attributes or show increment/decrement buttons. Internet Explorer 10 does not show increment/decrement buttons.*

http://caniuse.com/input-number

Answer (score 0):

The input type number is not supported by the Firefox browser

You can refer to the w3schools link here

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela i Got it, Won't be using it Next time.